# Hyperparameter tuning in multiclass classification problem: scoring metric relevant?

Tags: machine-learning, model-evaluation, metric

I'm working with an imbalanced multi class dataset. I try to tune the parameters of a `DecisionTreeClassifier`, `RandomForestClassifier` and a `GradientBoostingClassifier`using a randomized search and a bayesian search.

For now I used just `accuracy` for the scoring which is not really applicable for assessing my models performance (which I'm not doing). Is it also not suitable for the parameter tuning?

I found that for example `recall_micro` yields the same results as `accuracy`. This should be the same for other metrics like `f1_micro`.

**So my question is**: Is the scoring relevant? Can a different metric lead to different results? If yes, which metric should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the scoring is relevant.

Hyperparameter tuning is done by ranking hyperparameter sets and choosing the best one. The best one here is identified by a scoring metric. Ideally you would want the scoring metric to be identical with the final evaluation metric.

For an imbalanced multiclass dataset I would recommend to use average classwise accuracy (mean of diagonal of the normalized confusion matrix), since it is not biased towards the class with the highest number of samples.

Comment: Ok thanks! Why do for example `recall_micro` and `accuracy` lead to the same results when I do hyperparameter tuning?

Comment: That is dataset dependent. If I sort all humans by (a) feet size and (b) body size - why is the first person the same in both cases (lets just assume it is)? Because the measures are not independent of each other. Or without some strange analogy - because the hyperparameter set that achieves high accuracy also achieved high recall_micro - and vice versa.

Comment: Ok, I was just referring to the scikit learn doc: _Note that for “micro”-averaging in a multiclass setting with all labels included will produce equal precision, recall and F, while “weighted” averaging may produce an F-score that is not between precision and recall._ Since I want to use a metric already implemented by sci kit learn, which would you recommend for imbalanced multiclass problems? (Especially the averaging method: weighted, micro, macro, ..)

Comment: Weighted - weights should be the class sample numbers

Comment: Ok, but my problem is that if I calculate `recall_weighted` and `accuracy` for a multiclass problem I'm getting the exact same results (using the sklearn implementations).I'm just interested if there is an actual difference in the multiclass evaluation case. However if I choose `recall_macro` all classes are equal and I get naturally a lower result, just not sure if this is useful or not. `recall_macro` should be the metric you meant with "classwise accuracy"?